# While loop continues even after exception is raised (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I have a while loop that runs through two lists and when the list index is out of range I would like for it to break out of the while loop and end.

```
cipher = string_toList(cipher)
plain  = string_toList(plain)
i = 0                     ## holds value for first two letter block                                             
j = 2                     ## holds value for next two letter block and is updated to find invertable matrix     
p1 = val(plain[i]); p2 = val(plain[i+1])
c1 = val(cipher[i]); c2 = val(cipher[i+1])

try:
    while True:
        p3 = val(plain[j]); p4 = val(plain[j+1])
        c3 = val(cipher[j]); c4 = val(cipher[j+1])
        b = [p1, p2, p3, p4]
        c = [c1, c2, c3, c4]
        det = det_matrix(b)
        if gcd(det, 26) == 1:
            break
        j += 2             ## incrimented by two in order to hold consistent blocks of letters                  
except:
    print ("plaintext input is not sufficient enough to find key matrix") 


return b,c,det
```

Instead this program prints out the message after the except and then does not close on the terminal and continues the while loop. I do not know what i am doing wrong, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

when you catch the Except, and handle it with print, you aren't telling the program to exit.  you need to add `sys.exit()`